# Getting the parameter sent with pushnamed argument in the controller

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

```
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, QuestionScreen.routeName,
        arguments: paper);
```

I am sending data to questionscreen but i want to take it in the question controller firstly.
For state management i am using riverpod and provider and for routing ongenerateroute.

```
class QuestionsController {}
```

how can i get the arguments in the QuestionsController?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments;` to get the arguments.

```dart
class QuestionScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final args = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments; // use as with nullable if needed 
    if (args != null) {
      print(args);
    }
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want the stateless class to extend, how should I edit it?

Comment: Can you include your `QuestionScreen`

Comment: There is nothing on the question screen, I want to process it in the controller

Comment: Then I might call controller before going to the next route.  or will follow this `ModalRoute`, It will easier if you include more snippet that will reproduce the same issue

Comment: Wouldn't it be a problem to get the argument with the questions controller model route because if I send parameters to the controller with the argument in another place, how will it know which one I want?

Comment: `ModalRoute` will get the thing you will pass, I think it wont cause issue based on current situation, give a try, if fails consider including minimal snippet